# Azure AD - App registration - clientId/secret vs multi-tenant app?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-service-principal

Say I have an `App1` in `Tenant1`. This `App1` has contributor access to a subscription `SUB_1` in the same Tenant1. There is a `App1_ClientId` and `App1_ClientSecret` associated with the App1.

Now, I can use this id and secret to login to that tenant and do stuff with the `SUB_1` using the URL:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/Tenant1_ID/oauth2/token
```

Now how does it make a difference if this App is single tenant App or Multi Tenant App? Using this Id/Secret, I can access login to this app from any service anywhere.

Also, What does it mean by "Adding users to this App" ? Say if i add a user to this app, does it mean that that user will have access to the subscription in Tenant1 as well?

Answer (score 1):

> Now how does it make a difference if this App is single tenant App or
> Multi Tenant App? Using this Id/Secret, I can access login to this app
> from any service anywhere.

The difference would come if you want this application to be available in other tenants.

With single tenant, the Service Principal will be created only in your tenant. If you make this application multi-tenant, once a user in a different tenant consents to the application a Service Principal will be created in that tenant. That Service Principal must be granted appropriate Azure RBAC permissions in Azure Subscriptions associated with that other tenant. Only then your application will be able to perform operations on an Azure Subscription using client id/secret.

> Also, What does it mean by "Adding users to this App" ?

When you create an application, you can define some roles specific to that application. When you add users to the application, you can assign users in one or more of those roles and then whenever your users access the application, they will be able to do operations allowed by those roles.

To elaborate, let's say your application is a Web API that has 2 controllers actions - `Get` and `Post`. What you can do is restrict the access to these controller actions based on the application roles. A user in appropriate role will be able to access those controller action.

> Say if i add a user to this app, does it mean that that user will have
> access to the subscription in Tenant1 as well?

Not necessarily true. If you're invoking Azure management APIs on behalf of the signed-in user, then they must be assigned proper Azure RBAC role to perform operations. However if you're invoking Azure Management APIs on behalf of the application, then you can configure your application so that these APIs are called in appropriate portions in your code which are protected by the application roles. For example, you would want to implement read operation in your `Get` controller action and a create operation in your `Post` controller action.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, if App1 was a single tenant app, it will only have access to the resources granted to it in Tenant1. While you can use that app_id and secret in a code that runs anywhere: in that tenant, in another tenant or even in another cloud, the code can only access the relevant resources in Tenant1.

If you want your app to be able to access resources across multiple tenants, it needs to be added to each of those tenants by an administrator in the respective tenants. This can only be achieved when you have configured App1 as a multi-tenant application.

Adding a user to an application allows the user to access the application itself. The user does not automatically get/inherit any permissions that are granted to the application (such as a role in a subscription in your case)